# What does "conversation" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "attitude"?

"At the very least, the Fed's desire to step up the pace of policy normalization has changed the **conversation** at many central banks globally," said Sean Callow, an economist with Westpac in Sydney.

source:http://ca.reuters.com/article/businessNews/idCAKBN16N0OC-OCABS

Answer (score 1):

This is just a fancy way of saying "affected bankers".

Imagine businessmen conversing at a bank. What are they talking about? Banking, investments, and other such economic matters.

Now something, namely "Fed's desire to step up the pace of policy normalization", has happened which has changed some of those conversations. In addition to their usual banter, the bankers might be discussing the Fed's new policies and speculating on how their business will be affected.

Answer (score 1):

The "movers and shakers" at the banks discuss action plans based on various assumptions.  When a major assumption changes, like the Fed signalling a possible change in policy, that can cause a radical change in the options considered and plans made by the bankers.  "Changing the conversation" refers to a substantial change in the nature and parameters of their discussions; not just the actual conversations, but attitudes and perspectives.